# Spring Boot Actuator doesn't work after upgrading to 2.7.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, build.gradle, spring-boot-actuator

I have upgraded the old Spring Boot (It's actually Spring Batch) code from 1.4.0 to 2.7.2
Everything seems to work normally, except I need health indicators (/actuator/health) but I am not able to resolve this.

[image]

Error (I do understand the error, but do not know how to resolve it. Maybe there is some incompatibility in the build.gradle file):

```
07:54:08.887 [default task-2] ERROR org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/actuator/health] due to exception [Found interface com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster, but class was expected]
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster, but class was expected
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.couchbase.CouchbaseHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(CouchbaseHealthIndicator.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getLoggedHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:172)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:458)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:111)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:390)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
        mavenCentral()
        
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.2")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

version = '1.5'
war {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
    archiveName 'ApplicationDataExtractor.war'
    metaInf { from 'src/main/resources/META-INF/*' }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.7.2'
    
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.7.2'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:1.55'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.55'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.7.2'
    implementation 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.5.2'
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.2'     
    implementation 'org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-oxm:5.3.22'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.2'
    implementation 'org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.10'
    implementation files('jdbclibs/ojdbc7.jar')
    implementation files('jdbclibs/ucp.jar')
    implementation files('jdbclibs/bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar')
    implementation files('jdbclibs/CouchbaseIntegration-1.0.jar')
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-couchbase:3.2.6.RELEASE'   
    implementation 'com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.7.13'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.2'
    compileOnly 'javax:javaee-api:8.0.1'
    
    implementation group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    implementation group: 'commons-configuration', name: 'commons-configuration', version: '1.9'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.12'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {

    into "lib"

    from configurations.runtimeClasspath

}
task allDeps {
doLast {
    println "All Dependencies:"
    allprojects.each { p ->
        println()
        println " $p.name ".center( 60, '*' )
        println()
        p.configurations.all.findAll { !it.allDependencies.empty }.each { c ->
            println " ${c.name} ".center( 60, '-' )
            c.allDependencies.each { dep ->
                println "$dep.group:$dep.name:$dep.version"
            }
            println "-" * 60
        }
    }
    }
}

springBoot {
  mainClass = "com.XYZ.om.apm.batch.ApplicationDataExtractorBoot"
}

    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
}
configurations {
  compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
  compile.exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat'
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other detail. Your help is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Remove the versions from the starter dependencies. Instead of `spring-data-couchbase` use `spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase`. Remove `spring-oxm`, remove `spring-security` dependencies and add `sprig-boot-starter-security` instead. Also remove the `com.couchbase.client:java-client` which is now being pulled in by the starter. This way you will always use compatible versions.

Answer (score 1):

Your dependencies are conflicting and confusing, try to use the `spring-boot-starter-*` projects as much as possible and remove the versions (those are already managed).

For Spring Data Couchbase use a starter and let Spring Boot manage the driver version.

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'       
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase'
    implementation 'com.couchbase.client:java-client'

    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:1.55'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.55'
    implementation 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.5.2'
    
    implementation 'org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.2'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.2'
    implementation 'org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.10'
    implementation files('jdbclibs/ojdbc7.jar')
    implementation files('jdbclibs/ucp.jar')
    implementation files('jdbclibs/bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar')
    implementation files('jdbclibs/CouchbaseIntegration-1.0.jar')
    compileOnly 'javax:javaee-api:8.0.1'
    
    implementation group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    implementation group: 'commons-configuration', name: 'commons-configuration', version: '1.9'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

Something like this should fix it (and be better upgradeable as well).